# javascript library for mapping a path from gps data

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, dictionary, gps

I'm working on an app that takes gps data from a phone, sends it to the server, then maps the gps data onto a map on the web.
I plan on passing the data from the server to the client side with JSON, then constructing the map.

Does anyone know of a good library for this?
I've searched around and can't seem to find one that fits how I want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) comes to mind.